# Reverse string(Swaping)

Tags: c

I need help about this exam.I need to reverse the input string.

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[30];
    int strlen; int i=0; int count=0;int temp;int j;
    printf("Enter the string \n");
    gets(str);

    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
        i++;
        count++;
    }
    strlen=count;
    printf("The length of the string:%d\n", strlen);
    i=0;
    j=strlen;

    while(i<j)
    {
        temp=str[i];
        str[i]=str[j];
        str[j]=temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    printf("Reverse string :%s",str);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that at the end its not show me the string.
It shows me :

```
"Reverse string :"
```

and that is, no reverse string. Where is my mistake?

Comment: It's probably because the '\0' character is now on the first position after the reversal. You should decrement `count` after the first while loop.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't name a variable `strlen`, as this name is reserved for a standard function, *even if you do not include the standard header that is supposed to provide it*.

Comment: You could also use strlen(string_which_characters_you_want_to_count) to get the length (you have to include <string.h>

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are doing

```
j=strlen;
```

j points to the last index of the string which will be '\0'

And later in the loop you set `str[i]=str[j];`

Therefore, the first index will be `\0`

Printing str will display nothing

In order to make the code correct set `j=strlen - 1;`

Comment: Nice to hear it worked. Accept and upvote if the issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

As In your code you are assigning `j=strlen` pointing to `\0` or `null` character change it to `j=strlen-1;`

```
char str[30];
int strlen;int i=0;int count=0;int temp;int j;
printf("Enter the string \n");
gets(str);

while(str[i]!='\0')
{
    i++;
    count++;
}
 strlen=count;
printf("The lenht of the string:%d\n",strlen);
i=0;
j=strlen-1;

while(i<j)
{
    temp=str[i];
    str[i]=str[j];
    str[j]=temp;
    i++;
    j--;
}
printf("Reverse string :%s",str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the assignment `j=strlen;'. 
People will suggest you to change it to`j=strlen - 1;`

But, I'll recommend to resolve at its root.

```
while(str[i]!='\0')
{
    i++;
    count++;
}
```

After this loop, `count` will hold value as the index which has a '\0' of the string. Here, you should decrement `count` and then assign it to `strlen`. That makes the code more understandable.

With this change, you'll also have to change

```
printf("The length of the string: %d\n", strlen);
```

to

```
printf("The length of the string: %d\n", strlen+1);
```

as it would print

```
The length of the string: 4
```

instead of `5` for `"Hello"` because of the decrement.

Additionally, `strlen` is a function once you include `string.h` header file in your code. To keep it portable, you should always use naming convention which won't have standard, common function names (such as `strlen`) as a variable name in your code.

A slightly better version (using purely your logic) than your existing code will use one variable less, and will look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //char str[30] = "Hello";
    char str[30] = { [0 ... 29] = 0 };
    //int str_length = 0;
    int i = 0, count = 0, j = 0;
    char temp = 0;  //This should be a char rather than an int
    printf("Enter the string \n");
    gets(str);

    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
        i++;
        count++;
    }
    printf("The length of the string: %d\n", count);

    if(count) count--;

    //str_length = count;
    i = 0;
    j = count;

    while(i < j)
    {
        temp=str[i];
        str[i]=str[j];
        str[j]=temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    printf("Reverse string :%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```